# If apostrophe-S is possessive, should "it's" be used when referring to an object's possessions or not?

Tags: grammar, possessives

For example, which is correct:

> The robot can then compute it's coordinates.

or

> The robot can then compute its coordinates.

What's the rule here? It seems a little inconsistent.

Comment: The more common pronouns are exempt from using an apostrophe to denote possession, since the apostrophe is needed to denote contraction, and since the pronouns never append "s" to make a plural.

Comment: "Its" as a possessive is a special case, and definitely is not consistent with normal apostrophe rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apostrophe-S is used to form the possessive for **nouns only**.

All possessive pronouns are *not* apostrophized:

- his
- hers
- its
- mine
- yours
- theirs
- ours

Comment: **Most** possessive pronouns are not apostrophised. One needs to be careful with one's assertions.

Answer (score -1):

"it's" is a major grammatical mistake here

Use:

*The robot can then compute **its [own?]** coordinates.*

"Own" is necessary if these are robot's own coordinates.

Comment: Good point about "own"